# Elasticsearch: no such index - Symfony FOS/elastica-bundle

Tags: php, symfony, indexing, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I try to get first experiences with Elasticsearch.
Therefore I build a simple web app with Symfony and used the [FOSElasticaBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle) for Elastica integration. Now when i try to populate the index via the console i get the following error:

```
[2015-12-17 19:24:15,580][INFO ][rest.suppressed          ] /elasticsearch_test/ Params: {index=elasticsearch_test}
[elasticsearch_test] IndexNotFoundException[no such index]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver$WildcardExpressionResolver.resolve(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:566)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver.concreteIndices(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:133)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver.concreteIndices(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:77)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.delete.TransportDeleteIndexAction.checkBlock(TransportDeleteIndexAction.java:75)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.delete.TransportDeleteIndexAction.checkBlock(TransportDeleteIndexAction.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction.innerExecute(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:94)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction.doExecute(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.delete.TransportDeleteIndexAction.doExecute(TransportDeleteIndexAction.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.delete.TransportDeleteIndexAction.doExecute(TransportDeleteIndexAction.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.doExecute(NodeClient.java:58)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:347)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.FilterClient.doExecute(FilterClient.java:52)
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.BaseRestHandler$HeadersAndContextCopyClient.doExecute(BaseRestHandler.java:83)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:347)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesAdmin.execute(AbstractClient.java:1183)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesAdmin.delete(AbstractClient.java:1323)
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.action.admin.indices.delete.RestDeleteIndexAction.handleRequest(RestDeleteIndexAction.java:50)
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.BaseRestHandler.handleRequest(BaseRestHandler.java:54)
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.executeHandler(RestController.java:207)
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:166)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.HttpServer.internalDispatchRequest(HttpServer.java:128)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.HttpServer$Dispatcher.dispatchRequest(HttpServer.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty.NettyHttpServerTransport.dispatchRequest(NettyHttpServerTransport.java:348)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty.HttpRequestHandler.messageReceived(HttpRequestHandler.java:63)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.messageReceived(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:60)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpChunkAggregator.messageReceived(HttpChunkAggregator.java:145)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived(HttpContentDecoder.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:459)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:536)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:75)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My config:

```
fos_elastica:
clients:
    default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
indexes:
    app:
        client: default
        types:
            elasticsearch_test:
                mappings:
                    name:
                        type: string
                    brand : ~
                    flavours : ~
                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model: ESBundle/Entity/Test
                    finder: ~
                    provider: ~
                    listener: ~
```

I hope someone of you can help me
Thanks
Jupdi

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the newest version of ElasticSearchBundle which is 3.1 that does not support Elasticsearch 2.1.1.. To make this work you have to use Elasticsearch version 1.7.4

P.S Im pretty sure that mapping in `ESBundle/Entity/Test` should be like `ESBundle\Entity\Test`